# Hitting Enter on input text trigger first button's "click" event

Tags: javascript, html

I have this simple [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-browser-lxuth) (well, actually not mine, but I found it) and it works as expected when I click the "Add" button...!

But when I hit enter on the input field, the date input suddenly moves one day backward, because the "Prev" button received a "click" event...!

I've been trying to make sense of this problem, but I can't...!

Comment: You can see which button has press and if is enter button use `prevent.default()`

Comment: Set the type of your buttons to button, otherwise the button acts like a form submission.  `<button type='button'>`  From MDN for the type attribute -> `submit: The button submits the form data to the server. This is the default if the attribute is not specified`

Comment: And because your `Prev` button is classed as a submit button it captures the enter key, rather than the one you marked as `submit`,.. Personally I think having the default for `type` be equal to `submit` seems strange.  Web standards can just be strange sometimes.. :)